# Makevar Settings for R from Homebrew

Tags: r, macos, homebrew

I install and use home-brew on my mac's and always run into configuration issues with a few packages.  The latest being 'jpeg'.

This is primarily due to the packages not searching /usr/local/include and lib.  I've bounced around the internet and bit's of R documentation, but I can't find much about the canonical way to set LDFLAGS and CFLAGS for all packages.

So the question is, what is the canonical way to set LDFLAGS and CFLAGS for all packages through Makevar?

My ~/.R/Makevars file currently looks like this:

```
CC=gcc-4.9
CXX=g++-4.9
R_XTRA_CFLAGS=-std=c99 -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS+=-L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Are you using a version of R packaged by Homebrew (this should already work if you are, I think) or are you using the official binary installer?

Comment: I'm using the R version packaged from homebrew